# Can we use AWS ACM Public Certificate for external website applications?

Tags: aws-acm, aws-acm-certificate

Is this ACM public certificates used with ACM-integrated service only? OR can we use this for externally hosted applications as well?

I need a TLS certificate (PEM-encoded) for your subdomain and the 2048-bit private key (PEM-encoded).
to configure it in OKTA Admin console.  Ref: https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/custom-url-domain/main/#update-your-dns-txt

My preference is to generate SSL/TLS public certificate from AWS ACM as its free? However, I am not sure as AWS guidelines highlight that "AWS Certificate Manager and used exclusively with ACM-integrated services, such as Elastic Load Balancing, Amazon CloudFront, and Amazon API Gateway, are free.
You pay for the AWS resources you create to run your application. "

Could some one clarify this pls? Thanks.

Comment: ACM will not give you access to the private key. "Let's encrypt" is free as well, why not use that?

Comment: @luk2302 You're right. ACM doesn't share private keys. ACM public certificates are exclusively for AM-integrated services like  Elastic Load Balancing, Amazon CloudFront, and Amazon API Gateway. thanks for highlighting this.

Answer (score 0):

@luk2302 You're right. ACM doesn't share private keys. ACM public certificates are exclusively for AM-integrated services like  Elastic Load Balancing, Amazon CloudFront, and Amazon API Gateway. thanks for highlighting this.